# Proving that $a_n=n$ diverges.

Tags: limits, proof-writing, divergence-operator

The proof in my lectures notes for the divergence of $a_n=n$ is as follows:

Let $L \in \mathbb{R}$. Let $\epsilon=1$. Let $N \in \mathbb{N}$. By the Archimedean property, $\exists n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $n > L$. Let $m=max(n,N)+1$. Then $m-L \geq n-L + 1$ and $m > N$. This shows L isn't a limit. I'm wondering why the proof didn't stop at the "$n > L$" part since it tells us that for whatever value $L$ we have we can find an $n$, which is obviously in the sequence, greater than L. And also, if the proof isn't supposed to end there, shouldn't the last step be "$m > n$" rather than "$m > N$?

Comment: $L$ is a limit of $a_n$ $\iff$ for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $N \in \mathbb N$ such that $|a_m - L| < \epsilon$ for all $m > N$. Negating this statement, we have: $L$ is not a limit of $a_n$ $\iff$ there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that for every $N \in \mathbb N$, there is some $m > N$ for which $|a_m - L| > \epsilon$. So, we need to find such a specimen for **every** $N \in \mathbb N$. In other words, we need to show that no matter how far we go out into the sequence, we can continue to find elements satisfying $|a_m - L| > \epsilon$. (i.e. there are infinitely many such elements)

Comment: If you stop the demonstration at "$\exists n  \in \mathbb{N}, n>L$", you need to use the argument that $(a_n)$ is increasing and that the limit of a converging and increasing sequence is an upper bound of this sequence. This property is likely not proven yet at this point of your lectures...